# OnCreateView() happening before OnCreate() completed causing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a an Android fragment which essentially displays a custom ListView. My Fragment looks like this:

```cs
public class ResultSummaryFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        private List<ResultSummary> data;

        public override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            ISharedPreferences preferences = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
            string id = preferences.GetString("ID", string.Empty);

            if (id != null)
            {
                RunnerData RunnerData = new RunnerData(id);
                // This is not happening before OnCreateView?
                data = await RunnerData.GetAllResults();
            }
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Context context = Application.Context;

            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.results_summary_view, container, false);
            ListView listview = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.AllResultsListView);

            //data is being passed in as null...
            ResultsSummaryListAdapter adapter = new ResultsSummaryListAdapter(context, data);
            listview.Adapter = adapter;

            return view;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `data` being passed into `ResultsSummaryListAdapter` is null because the `OnCreateView()` code seems to get executed before `data = await RunnerData.GetAllResults();` returns. I'm absolutely sure that this does return data (it can take time due to download time).

What am I doing wrong here?

I feel like a better way to handle this would be to instantiate the fragment, start getting the data and then trigger the below code:

```cs
ResultsSummaryListAdapter adapter = new ResultsSummaryListAdapter(context, data);
listview.Adapter = adapter;
```

I'm not sure how to go about that in Android.

Comment: why you have used `async ` before onCreate() ?

Comment: If you want to update the view with OnCreateView, you could check the similar question in the link. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97359/how-do-i-update-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below links on how to use Fragments to achieve your requirements.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/implementing-with-fragments/

The below link gives you an overview of fragments and is well explained.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/

Also, the attached image will explain to you the life cycle of fragments.
[image]

Comment: The reason I ended up doing the API call in `OnCreate` is because you can't return a task from OnCreateView(), so can't use async methods. Unfortunately `public override async View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` is not valid code.

Comment: However, I do think I'm going about this the entirely wrong way. I feel like there's a better solution whereby I create the fragment etc, then the view is updated once data is available... But I'm not sure how to achieve that. The Android lifecycle is very new to me.

Comment: @WSC, Sorry I didn't notice the method name. You're right I have edited the answer on how to use the fragments. Please check.